# Missing detail in answer to HTTP-OPTION

Tags: rest, http, http-post, http-options-method, preflight

I'm trying to find out the problem in a communication issue between my klient and a REST API.
I can identify the problem but I'm not sure what is exactly missing in the answer for the OPTION request.
My application is creating a HTTP POST what is preflighted by the browser with a HTTP-OPTION. The option is asking for approving the custom Content-type. After the server answers the OPTION the POST is not sent.

```
OPTIONS /element_collection/VizRundown/channels/ExampleChannel/playlists/continuous/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8580
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0.........
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US......
Origin: null
```

Here is how the answer looks like:

```
200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Allow: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Content-Type: text/plain
Server: MediaSequencer/1.23.1.11957 soul/014dfd135460
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Am I correct that there should be a line int the answer approving the requested Content-Type? Like this:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not required as per the relevant sections of the spec.

http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-preflight-requests:

> In response to a preflight request the resource indicates which
>   methods and headers (other than simple methods and simple headers) it
>   is willing to handle and whether it supports credentials.

http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#terminology:

> A header is said to be a simple header if the header field name is an
>   ASCII case-insensitive match for Accept, Accept-Language, or
>   Content-Language or if it is an ASCII case-insensitive match for
>   Content-Type and the header field value media type (excluding
>   parameters) is an ASCII case-insensitive match for
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain.